# Mouse without Borders from Database

Tags: mouse, kvm, screensharing

I'm trying to do a network-wide install of a program similar to Mouse without Borders - the goal is to install the program on around 20 computers and then have a database that tells the program which computers to connect with Mouse without Borders, etc.

Does anyone know of an existing solution to it?

The db would tell the program "Computer 1: connected to --> Computer 18", for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on synergy : http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/

> Synergy lets you easily share a single mouse and keyboard between multiple >computers with different operating systems without special hardware. It's >intended for users with multiple computers on their desk since each system >uses its own display.

I used it between a Windows 7 and an Ubuntu 13.04 for a while.